# Distribution Over Finite Support With Particular Moments

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Given the first and second moments of a distribution supported on $[0,1]$, what are the conditions such that the distribution be well defined. For example, if $X \sim F(x)$ such that $X\in[0,1]$, is it possible that $\mathbb{E}X < \mathbb{E}X^2$? $\mathbb{E}X > \mathbb{E}X^2$? Etc.

From another question, I came across the [*Hausdorff moment problem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_moment_problem), which seems to indicate that the second moment must be smaller than the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X\in[0,1]$ then $X^2 \leq X$ and the inequality of moments follows.